# Why is restoring a fresh database from a backup failing due to a duplicate key error?

Tags: mysql, replication, backup, mariadb, duplication

I'm trying to build a replica from an active database with no downtime for replication purposes.

I run the following statement to get a backup, avoid locking the tables, and flush the logs so that the replica can pick up replication from when the dump started:

`mysqldump -uroot -p --skip-lock-tables --single-transaction --flush-logs --master-data=2 -A > dump.sql`

I then transfer this file over to my fresh replica with no database tables, and run `mysql -uroot -p < dump.sql`, yet I receive a duplicate key error somehow about halfway through the import:

`Duplicate entry '<misc text here>' for key 'floats':36`

I'm struggling to figure out why this is happening. Does this indicate duplicate keys in my primary active database? In this case, wouldn't the database be broken and spitting out errors?

Comment: So, when you query the source database for `'<misc text here>'` in that column, how many rows do you get? It would also help to see the definitions of table and index(es) in question.

Comment: Check character sets and collations.  Pleasse provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  Can you find "'floats':36" in the dump?  Twice?  What datatypes are the column(s) involved?

Comment: Are you replicating from the right spot, `master-data=2` is a commented position.

Comment: While comparing MySQL server removes trailing spaces on 5.x and takes them into account on 8+. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&rdbms2=mysql_5.7&fiddle=d68322305772e6acf1e64428da4118d7